# How to decrypt a signed RSA message without using private/public key in Mathematica?

Tags: cryptography

```
    Code

In[210]:= ClearAll["`*"]

In[211]:= nAlice = 942379549442875863440792026289676733726442280425825833;

In[212]:= eAlice = 3161;

In[213]:= nBob = 79850514653997998597600783722865275412086926043219979;

In[214]:= eBob = 8171;

In[215]:= AbsoluteTiming[FactorInteger[nBob]]

Out[215]= {15.5277, {{135920551079483184945633467, 1}, {587479332741251690052305137, 
   1}}}

In[216]:= AbsoluteTiming[FactorInteger[nAlice]]

Out[216]= {15.5157, {{950161244808815071986341851, 1}, {991810131797677153304382283, 
   1}}}

In[217]:= pBob = 135920551079483184945633467

Out[217]= 135920551079483184945633467

In[218]:= qBob = 587479332741251690052305137

Out[218]= 587479332741251690052305137

In[220]:= CheckPBOBandQBOBisNBOB = pBob*qBob; 

In[221]:= CheckPBOBandQBOBisNBOB == nBob

Out[221]= True

In[222]:= \[Phi]Bob = (pBob - 1)*(qBob - 1)

Out[222]= 79850514653997998597600782999465391591352051045281376

In[223]:= dBob = PowerMod[eBob, -1, \[Phi]Bob]

Out[223]= 8746323658711076825951866452640010460685361116818851

In[224]:= pAlice = 950161244808815071986341851

Out[224]= 950161244808815071986341851

In[225]:= qAlice = 991810131797677153304382283

Out[225]= 991810131797677153304382283

In[226]:= CheckPALICEandQALICEisNALICE = pAlice*qAlice;

In[227]:= CheckPALICEandQALICEisNALICE  == nAlice

Out[227]= True

In[228]:= \[Phi]Alice = (pAlice - 1)*(qAlice - 1)

Out[228]= 942379549442875863440792024347705357119950055135101700

In[229]:= dAlice = PowerMod[eAlice, -1, \[Phi]Alice]

Out[229]= 563460091251830237868743095861171504257103955775179441

In[230]:= cipher = {77874568741928116959970598529095971025860629087414125, 
   495328811744891527856291411108284515481309125912040821, 
   369267441143730519486552355172358225351959954243105382, 
   124119224439232442304278849939683049126254632833712437, 
   20954238328685282593893345826949043203535916444385374, 
   470035748197881238544363935112112802526262356262748013, 
   928665615831283703818297614394854444081685899417409053, 
   136549435712631532796261906293828466502726501184053084, 
   670416167338086414037064641226988540538267588585588252, 
   567230880992106994477625733651596614938553331658312653, 
   85499759711527459137249750519966533739083416815698030, 
   237194267190181172048965935283718337718749307564150239, 
   714940137644676544345837579711131076374048982073080384, 
   245202745375389337687548072467435228030738801235203381, 
   615798346416635545198716207339517311423843506763563210, 
   213861629662009084700094170270897896167083142563121180, 
   687507111871183164556540582320572223190911067058656586, 
   151206066523006982482036176972140280229959592662783715, 
   238434706300724254272644179998180762810110457064427775, 
   632893072732510932417630599227031114123544559673433880, 
   111253190643850701616200389944385735772515201477791379};

In[159]:= 
c1 = PowerMod[cAlice, eAlice, nAlice]

Out[159]= {53132731837440434547009702248721568338805404985817658, \
69540645986149689226714225714238822549727958387239172, \
7754537788541816511353949315771583230643363155275654, \
10632842904637884543730305601152596891244548641300284, \
44364698378263153436111702142488389245494700289027636, \
63388254804271803219769871467303892115199170764959786, \
16212391704058420639692906479221189600249367495853130, \
71649516473218468929927344516043816757158682877843178, \
64279751614262005085023176463942140616807811924070564, \
62137129688404336913445615424078316013945251807998586, \
20355232507548573436577612747187823915428639143950500, \
51597199912887585200473359895279515077043096035107570, \
59736339472114782168722956340795541474882957243580160, \
46661476490413632637187732567003741586666235008809184, \
72814049661621294436193340859951669300801131370986919, \
68147338124333931333169886682098872619390566476160110, \
44771964624017859554589254594674370739144045835265971, \
30243156959706048380330503429340975327646226339351684, \
957907768693084406076261446953050125746887557130395, \
75174109814970694655418370232300551391685976579249692, \
71103072233909234453323914233061989068431229490907036}

B = 256;

In[231]:= mAlice = PowerMod[c1, dBob, nBob]

Out[231]= PowerMod[c1, 8746323658711076825951866452640010460685361116818851, \
79850514653997998597600783722865275412086926043219979]

In[232]:= firstcharacter = Mod[mAlice, B]

Out[232]= Mod[PowerMod[c1, 8746323658711076825951866452640010460685361116818851, 
  79850514653997998597600783722865275412086926043219979], B]

In[233]:= q = mAlice; ascii = {};
While[q != 0,
  AppendTo[ascii, Mod[q, B]];
  q = Quotient[q, B]
  ];
ascii

Out[235]= {}

In[236]:= messageFromAlice = FromCharacterCode[ascii]

Out[236]= ""
```

This is my code. This is an RSA signed message. I'm trying to decrypt the cipher using mathematica but the last 2 steps keep failing and returning nothing. what am i doing wrong? I'm not allowed to use the built in functions private and public key which is why I have to decipher the message the long way. I don't know what else to try. The only other info I got was to use base 256 when converting the cipher into ascii and then to letters. I have seen examples of cracking decryptions like this when you're the one sending the message in text and encrypting it. But I am struggling to find examples where you're only given the cipher.

Comment: Does this help? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230687/72682  Please also avoid using In[...] and Out[...] and just copy your input, don't display the outputs here.

Comment: As I mentioned in that answer, you don't need mathematica's built-in public/private key functions - they're just being used for wrapping up the data there, but everything else there works.

Comment: omg, thank you so much!! I had so many questions and you literally answered all of them in one post. Sorry for not reading the other code properly, I saw public and private key and just assumed it was not what I was looking for. thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy to adapt from my other answer, but without using PublicKey / PrivateKey,

```
Remove["Global`*"];
ciphertext = {77874568741928116959970598529095971025860629087414125,
   495328811744891527856291411108284515481309125912040821, 
   369267441143730519486552355172358225351959954243105382, 
   124119224439232442304278849939683049126254632833712437, 
   20954238328685282593893345826949043203535916444385374, 
   470035748197881238544363935112112802526262356262748013, 
   928665615831283703818297614394854444081685899417409053, 
   136549435712631532796261906293828466502726501184053084, 
   670416167338086414037064641226988540538267588585588252, 
   567230880992106994477625733651596614938553331658312653, 
   85499759711527459137249750519966533739083416815698030, 
   237194267190181172048965935283718337718749307564150239, 
   714940137644676544345837579711131076374048982073080384, 
   245202745375389337687548072467435228030738801235203381, 
   615798346416635545198716207339517311423843506763563210, 
   213861629662009084700094170270897896167083142563121180, 
   687507111871183164556540582320572223190911067058656586, 
   151206066523006982482036176972140280229959592662783715, 
   238434706300724254272644179998180762810110457064427775, 
   632893072732510932417630599227031114123544559673433880, 
   111253190643850701616200389944385735772515201477791379};

aliceModulus = 942379549442875863440792026289676733726442280425825833;
alicePublicExponent = 3161;
bobModulus = 79850514653997998597600783722865275412086926043219979;
bobPublicExponent = 8171;
{aliceP, aliceQ} = FactorInteger[aliceModulus][[All, 1]];
{bobP, bobQ} = FactorInteger[bobModulus][[All, 1]];
totientAlice = (aliceP - 1) (aliceQ - 1);(*EulerPhi[aliceModulus]*)
totientBob = (bobP - 1) (bobQ - 1);(*EulerPhi[bobModulus]*)

alicePrivateExponent = PowerMod[alicePublicExponent, -1, totientAlice];
bobPrivateExponent = PowerMod[bobPublicExponent, -1, totientBob];

c1 = PowerMod[ciphertext, alicePublicExponent, aliceModulus];
decryptInteger[c_, d_, n_] := PowerMod[c, d, n]

toText[numbers_] := StringJoin[
   FromCharacterCode[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#, 256]]] & /@ numbers
];

stage1 = decryptInteger[#, bobPrivateExponent, bobModulus] & /@ c1;
toText@stage1
```

Result:

```
"Congratulations! You have now managed to crack the RSA cipher. This \
means that you have a pass grade for project 2. If you want to pursue \
the requirements for a higher grade you need to solve one more \
problem. The quote you should encrypt and crack is:Simplicity is a \
great virtue but it requires hard work to achieve it and education to \
appreciate it. And to make matters worse: complexity sells better. \
Edsger Dijkstra"
```